# How to add day of week to a MM/dd/yyyy csv column in Powershell using -replace?

Tags: date, csv, powershell

I would like to add a day-of-week 'ddd' value to a date field in a csv file that looks like this:

```
...,From,To,Date,Time,...
...,"Last, First","Last2, First2",11/30/2015,10:00 AM,...
```

to

```
...,"Last, First","Last2, First2",Mon 11/30/2015,10:00 AM,...
```

I am parsing the file line-by-line for other reasons, so adding the day to every date in the file using Import-Csv and Export-Csv is overkill.

Right now, I have code that looks like this:

```
Get-Content -Path $src | select -Skip 1 | foreach {
    # {Other code here}
    $out = $_ -replace ',(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}),', {get-date $1 -f ',ddd MM/dd/yyyy,'}
    Out-File -FilePath $dstDir\$file -InputObject $out -Encoding ascii -Append
}
```

Of course, Get-Date is not run as -replace assumes everything inside the brackets is a regex string.  Is there a way I can use Get-Date to add formatting using pipes?

EDIT: I ended up with the following code:

```
    if ($_ -match ',(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}),') {
        $day = Get-Date ([datetime]$matches[1]) -f ',ddd MM/dd/yyyy,'
        $out = $_ -replace ',(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}),', $day
        Out-File -FilePath $dstDir\$file -InputObject $out -Encoding ascii -Append
    }
```

Comment: Update to this: It looks like I will have to extract the substring using "-match", add the 'ddd' code, then use "-replace" to add it back in.  I wish there was an elegant inline solution, but for now, 3 lines will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Import-Csv -Path $src | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Date = Get-Date -Date ([datetime]$_.Date) -Format 'ddd MM/dd/yyyy'
    $_
} | Export-Csv -Path $dstDir\$file -NoTypeInformation
```

Or

```
Get-Content -Path $src | select -Skip 1 | foreach {

    # {Other code here}

    $DateRegex = ',(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}),'
    if($_ -match $DateRegex){
        $Date = $Matches[1]
        $out = $_ -replace $DateRegex,  (Get-Date -Date ([datetime]$Date) -f ',ddd MM/dd/yyyy,')
    }

    Out-File -FilePath $dstDir\$file -InputObject $out -Encoding ascii -Append
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use Import-csv and Export-csv as it is overkill for what I am doing (I would have to use your code before my code, and about 80% of the file is not being used).  I am already stepping through the file line-by-line, so I would prefer a method to replace the date using the Foreach {} I use now.

Comment: @T.G. Here you go, but look, how ugly it is!

Comment: Ugly indeed, but it works.  I wish there was an elegant inline solution to this.  My resulting code almost exactly matched yours!